# SQLite database in Android, causes application crash

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm testing SQLite database in android for the first time.
My program stops as I open it, and i cannot check it, i was wondering if there is a mistake in my code, or database connection,

any help will be appreciated :)

this is my Main.java file:

```
    package de.blattsoft.SQLite;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        Log.d("Ali", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName")));
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

> Note: I have asked this question many times ago, and I have written the full answer of how to implement databases in Android in the answers bellow.

Comment: Please post Logcat output.

Comment: Post your DBHelper class.

Comment: First post your log cat and in first view I see there may be a problem in this line  `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"))`.. In place of `"FirstNmae"` provide column name that you used in creating table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked this question many times ago when I was an Android noob! :D
right now this is the way I recommend you to use android sqlite database using helper classes.

> as an overview, we need to create two classes, `DatabaseHelper` class
>   and `DataSource` class.

**What we need to create:**

1. The `DatabaseHelper` class must extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` which is a built-in Android class from `android.database.sqlite` package and its purpose is to manage database creation and version management.
2. The `DataSource` class uses our helper class to implement methods which you need for your application.

*For Example, we're going to create a database which has one table called `users`, and the table has 2 columns: `id` and `name`;
The `id` is going to be used as the primary key.*

So, let's create the helper class:
  `DatabaseHelper.java:`

```
package com.mpandg.android.dbtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // this tag is used for logging purposes.
    public static final String TAG = "database";

    // database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // database file name.
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

    // table details:
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String USERS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String USERS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";


    // query of creating users table.
    public static final String CREATE_USERS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + " (" +
                    USERS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    USERS_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";

    // query string of deleting users table.
    public static final String DELETE_TABLES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS + ";";

    // constructor method which takes the context and passes it
    // to appropriate super method with other database details
    // which creates the database.
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        // creates the database using given information.
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // this line executes the query we made earlier
        // to create the users table.
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);

        // log the table creation for debugging.
        Log.i(TAG, TABLE_USERS + " has been created.");
    }

    // whenever you give a new update for your application,
    // if you change the version of the database, this method
    // will be called, you can do your own complicated operations
    // on your tables if you need, but right now, I just delete
    // the old table and I make an explicit call to onCreate
    // method to create the tables again.
    // but never forget that you should never make explicit
    // calls to onCreate method, but this is an exception here.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // execute the delete query we made earlier.
        db.execSQL(DELETE_TABLES);

        // explicit call to onCreate. (read the comment above method)
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

As you see, we have actually created a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` and we have implemented `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)` and `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)` methods, and the helper class we created, takes care of opening the database if it exists, creating it if it does not exist and upgrading it if it's necessary.

Now it's time to use the helper class we created and write our methods to use the database in `DataSource` class.

We will create a database object and we will instantiate it using the methods in our helper class, and we create methods to insert, select and delete.

So, Let's create `DataSource.java`:

```
package com.mpandg.android.dbtest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataSource {

    // create an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper
    // but we're going to instantiate it using
    // the helper class we created earlier.
    SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    // the main database object which will be
    // instantiated using the helper class methods.
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    private final String TAG = "dataSource";

    // an string array holding our table's column names
    // which is going to be used by database methods.
    public static final String[] usersTableColumns = {
            DatabaseHelper.USERS_COLUMN_ID,
            DatabaseHelper.USERS_COLUMN_NAME
    };

    // constructor which receives the activity context.
    public DataSource(Context context){

        // instantiate the dbHelper object using our DatabaseHelper class.
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void open(){

        // opening the database or
        // creating the table structures for the first time.
        // the helper class knows when to open or create the database.
        dataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // log the event for debugging purposes.
        Log.i(TAG, "database opened");
    }

    public boolean isOpen () {

        // check if the database is already open.
        return dataBase.isOpen();
    }

    public void close(){

        // close the database.
        dataBase.close();

        // log the event for debugging purposes.
        Log.i(TAG, "database closed");
    }

    // insert a name record into database .
    public void insertName (String name) {

        // ContentValues implements a map interface.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // put the data you want to insert into database.
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.USERS_COLUMN_NAME, name);

        // passing the string array which we created earlier
        // and the contentValues which includes the values
        // into the insert method, inserts the values corresponding
        // to column names and returns the id of the inserted row.
        long insertId = dataBase.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS , null, values);

        // log the insert id for debugging purposes.
        Log.i(TAG, "added name id:" + insertId);
    }

    // returns a list of string
    // containing the names saved in the database.
    public List<String> getNames (){

        List<String> names;

        // creating the cursor to retrieve data.
        // cursor will contain the data when the
        // query is executed.
        Cursor cursor = dataBase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS, usersTableColumns,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        // log the number of returned rows for debug.
        Log.i(TAG, "returned: " + cursor.getCount() + " name rows .");

        // check if the cursor is not null.
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){

            // instantiate the list.
            names = new ArrayList<>();

            // cursor starts from -1 index, so we should call
            // moveToNext method to iterate over the data it contains.
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                // read the string in the cursor row using the index which is the column name.
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.USERS_COLUMN_NAME));

                // log the retrieved name.
                Log.i(TAG, "name retrieved:" + name);

                // now add the retrieved name into the list.
                names.add(name);
            }

            // now we have the names in our string list
            return names;

        } else {

            // if the cursor was empty, it means that
            // there was no name found in the table,
            // so return null.
            return null;
        }


    }

    // returns a name corresponding to given id.
    public String findNameById (long id){

        String name;

        // the where clause which is our condition.
        String whereClause = DatabaseHelper.USERS_COLUMN_ID + " = ?";

        // the arguments passed to
        // the where clause. (here is only one argument)
        String[] whereArgs = {id+""};

        // creating the cursor to retrieve data.
        // cursor will contain the data when the
        // query is executed.
        Cursor cursor = dataBase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS, usersTableColumns,
                whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);

        // log the number of returned rows for debug.
        // (logically it should return one row here)
        Log.i(TAG, "returned: " + cursor.getCount() + " name rows .");

        // check if the cursor is not null.
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){

            // cursor starts from -1 index, so we should call
            // moveToNext method to iterate over the data it contains.
            cursor.moveToNext();

            // read the string in the cursor row using the index which is the column name.
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.USERS_COLUMN_NAME));

            // log the retrieved name.
            Log.i(TAG, "name retrieved:" + name);
            return name;

        } else {

            // if the cursor was empty, it means that
            // there was no name found with given id,
            // so return null.
            return null;
        }
    }

    // delete a name from the table.
    public void deleteName (String name) {

        // where statement of our delete method.
        String whereClause = DatabaseHelper.USERS_COLUMN_NAME + "=" + "?";

        // the arguments passed to
        // the where clause. (here is only one argument)
        String[] whereArgs = {name};

        // execute the delete query with delete method.
        int deleteId = dataBase.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS , whereClause, whereArgs);

        // log the id of the deleted row.
        Log.i(TAG, "deleted name id:" + deleteId);
    }
}
```

Now that we have done writing the necessary classes to create and use our database in an appropriate way, it's time to use the methods we wrote in our `DataSource` class.

**All you have to do, is to create an object of `DataSource` class in your activity and use the methods in it.**
when you are intending to use the database, you should open it, you can simply do it by the `open()` method we wrote in our `DataSource` class, and after you are done, you must close it to avoid leaks; you can close it using the `close()` method in 'DataSource` class.

For example, you have some users and you want to add them in the database:

```
// create the dataSource object
// "this" refers to the activity.
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(this);

// open the dataBase
dataSource.open();

// insert the names.
dataSource.insertName("Amy");
dataSource.insertName("Johnny");
dataSource.insertName("Abbey");
dataSource.insertName("Miley");

// close the database.
dataSource.close();
```

Or you want to log all the users in the database:

```
//TAG for debug logs.
String TAG = "db log";

// create the dataSource object
// "this" refers to the activity.
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(this);

// open the dataBase
dataSource.open();

// get the names.
List<String> names = dataSource.getNames();

// log all the names in the list.
for (String name: names) {
    Log.i(TAG, "retrieved name:" + name);
}

// close the database.
dataSource.close();
```

Or you want to find a name by its id:

```
//TAG for debug logs.
String TAG = "db log";

// create the dataSource object
// "this" refers to the activity.
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(this);

// open the dataBase
dataSource.open();

// find the name by id.
String name = dataSource.findNameById(1);

// log the retrieved name wit id:1.
Log.i(TAG, "retrieved name:" + name);

// close the database.
dataSource.close();
```

Finally if you want to delete a name:

```
// create the dataSource object
// "this" refers to the activity.
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(this);

// open the dataBase
dataSource.open();

// delete the given name
dataSource.deleteName("Amy");

// close the database.
dataSource.close();
```

That's it.
This is a basic structure for creating databases in Android, as you can see, you can add other tables and columns, easily by adding your own code to the helper class and your own methods to use them in the DataSource class.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to create a database, then insert some data in it an then try to display.

What you are doing is ,if database is not there then create and select the column and display. It will obviously fail and your app crash. 
Do something like

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    /*CREATE LOGIN TABLE*/
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}
```

Then do this ,

```
public void addMessage(String id, String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, id); // 
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Then you can display ,

Answer (score 2):

You haven't created the database. And inserting or fetching values from the structure which doesn't exist will lead to crash your app. It's like climbing a building which doesn't exist.

So, first create the database then do rest of the things.

For better understanding follow the you tube video tutorial of Slidenerd. They have sequentially explained all the things for beginners [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BUljVIgnoE&index=13&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW5JdoFT0Rlt3ry5Mjp7s8cT).

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you Saggy, Oh and i really liked your example, can you please provide a link to the video if possible? I really appreciate your help..

Comment: I have attached the link in my answer. It's a series of tutorial. Hope it will help.

Comment: I guess you should accept an answer and upvote it so this question get close with appropriate answer which helped you.

Comment: I know Saggy, but as you see,I'm a new user and I don't have enough reputation to do that :(  be sure I'll do that immediately when I earned some reputation..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
package ir.itstuff.SQLite;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    (EditText) fName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    (EditText) sName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    (Button) save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FirstName varchar,SecondName varchar);")

    //Inserting data from inputs
   save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String first_name = fName.getText().toString();
                    String second_name = sName.getText().toString();


                        String insert_data="INSERT INTO  MyTable (FirstName,SecondName) VALUES " + "('" + first_name + "'," + "'" + second_name + "'" + ")";
                        shoppingListDB.execSQL(insert_data);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    Cursor cr=shoppingListDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable;", null);

                    if  (cr.moveToFirst()){
                        do{
                            String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));

                        }
                        while (cr.moveToNext());

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;

                    }

                    cr.close();

                }
            });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I tested it and it had some errors, so i debugged it, and now this is the code                                                                                        I was just wondering that what does Cursor and getApplicationContext() do?

Comment: I have made a mistake there it was suppose to be `getBaseContext` not `getAppicationContext`, `getBaseContext` gets the contents of the current activity while cursor is used to search through the table.

Comment: Again, really really thank you for your answer, but may you please tell me that what do you mean with Contents of current activity? sorry for my elementary question, I'm still a newbie in android..

Comment: it returns the base context as set by the constructor or `setBaseContext` don't forget to my answer as correct.